# A CSS selector to get last visible div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

A tricky CSS selector question, don't know if it's even possible.

Lets say this is the HTML layout:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>  
<div></div>  
<div style="display:none"></div>
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

I want to select the last `div`, which is displayed (ie. not `display:none`) which would be the third `div` in the given example.
Mind you, the number of `div`s on the real page can differ (even the `display:none` ones).

Comment: One of the problems with this request is that, as a general principle, CSS can select an element only based on previous elements (ancestors or previous siblings), and not on anything that comes afterwards.  So your <div> can't get selected based on any properties of <div>s that come after it.

Comment: @Doin now possible on [up-to-date browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could select and style this with JavaScript or jQuery, but CSS alone can't do this.

For example, if you have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) implemented on the site, you could just do:

```
var last_visible_element = $('div:visible:last');
```

Although hopefully you'll have a class/ID wrapped around the divs you're selecting, in which case your code would look like:

```
var last_visible_element = $('#some-wrapper div:visible:last');
```

Comment: the question clearly says no "a JQuery CSS Selector", says "A CSS SELECTOR", this should be the accepted ANSWER =P

Comment: This is, indeed, the answer to the original question.  The questioner never mentioned javascript or jquery and those tags were added by another answerer.  1nfected - do you actually want jQuery?  If so, please actually put that in your question.  Otherwise, you should accept this answer instead.

Comment: I think jQuery is acceptable to the OP.  That was the accepted solution, after all.

Comment: Whhyyyy is the first answer allllwaaayyysss jquery? This is a _javascript_ answer to a _CSS_ question. CSS !== javascript

Comment: @dudewad: See the last part of the first sentence: "but CSS alone can't do this." The answer could leave it at that, with no alternative in sight... or provide an alternative. But this answer has at least done its due diligence in actually stating that CSS cannot do what is being asked (albeit it doesn't elaborate *why*). On the other hand, an answer that just goes off on a JavaScript solution without acknowledging the CSS nature of the question *is* worth criticizing.

Comment: Almost 2024 and jQuery is still the top answer to a CSS question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 56):

The real answer to this question is, you can't do it.
Alternatives to CSS-only answers are not correct answers to this question, but if JS solutions are acceptable to you, then you should pick one of the JS or jQuery answers here.
However, as I said above, the true, correct answer is that *you cannot do this in CSS reliably* unless you're willing to accept the `:not` operator with the `[style*=display:none]` and other such negated selectors, which only works on inline styles, and is an overall poor solution.

Comment: Firstly, I agree with you but I do think that using the `:not` operator as you stated can work in certain circumstances. For example, this works perfectly for my situation where I have JS conditionally hiding elements which then adds inline styles and thus your solution actually works perfectly :)

Comment: Well, then I guess what works works :) I'm just a bit of an idealist and I like to stress where things aren't the best, its important to be able to distinguish what is 'hacky' and what isn't because it makes us all better programmers.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya, I agree that this solution shouldn't be used as a css only solution to the OP query, I do think that this works very well when used in conjunction with JS though.

Comment: You might also use a CSS class to hide elements (instead of an inline style). If that's the case, you can just as well negate the selector for that hiding class. This always selects the same what is hidden because both are set by the same CSS class. So your answer goes in the right direction but not far enough. :-)

Comment: Agree. If you are using a media query to hide some elements, no pure CSS solution for now.

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
div:not([style*="display: none"]):last-child
```

Comment: makes total sense the selector, but since you need to select the last child itself, it must not be display none and get only the last child, so :not([style*="display: none"]):last-child

Comment: this is a perfect solution if you're planning on hiding some elements some of the times, e.g. using jQuery.

Comment: It does not select the last child

Comment: **This won't work,** because the two pseudo-selectors are independent filters that are combined _(not processed sequentially)_. It takes the intersection of `div:last-child` and `div:not(...)` and uses the result of this intersection. In other words, if the actual last child has `display: none` it won't be selected, but also, the div without this style won't be selected also if it's not the last child.

Answer (score 14):

If you can use inline styles, then you can do it purely with CSS.

I am using this for doing CSS on the next element when the previous one is visible:

```
div[style='display: block;'] + table {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: I would change it to `[style*='display: block']` since it could have `display: block !important;` or just `<div style="display: block">` :-)

Comment: It works for me in a css file like this `.btn-group > .btn.d-none + .btn` (used for bootstrap's input groups"

Answer (score 9):

I think it's not possible to select by a css value (display)

edit:

in my opinion, it would make sense to use a bit of jquery here:

```
$('#your_container > div:visible:last').addClass('last-visible-div');
```

Answer (score 6):

Pure JS solution (eg. when you don't use jQuery or another framework to other things and don't want to download that just for this task):

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var last;

if (divs) {
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].style.display != 'none') {
      last = divs[i];
    }
  }
}

if (last) {
  last.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div style="display:none">D</div>
<div style="display:none">E</div>
```

[External link](http://jsfiddle.net/uEeaA/90/)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, the only non-jQuery reply! However, this doesn't work when having multiple parent elements to apply to: http://jsfiddle.net/uEeaA/100/ - can you help me build a solution for others that works? I need it, others need it, so please help :)

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but for any future visitors, you could do something along the lines of http://jsfiddle.net/uEeaA/103/

Comment: I wanted to up vote this just b/c you dropped jQuery - good on you. My only complaint is a div can be hidden from view in many ways, not just based on the style parameter. Real quick: [1] width and height can be set to 0, [2] transform scale can be 0, [3] and we can place it out of the viewable area.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with CSS, however you could do this with jQuery.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sPK7m/2/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('li').not(':hidden').last().addClass("red");
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li class="hideme">Item 4</li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hideme {
    display:none;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

---

**jQuery (previous solution):**

```
var $items = $($("li").get().reverse());

$items.each(function() {

    if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
        $(this).addClass("red");
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: That's a lot of jQuery for `$('li:visible:last').addClass('red')`.

Comment: Huh? `$('li').not(':hidden').last().addClass("red");`

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, I solved this problem using pure css with the `:has` operator.

In your example you will have the following rule :
`div:has(+ div[style*="display:none"]`
It will select all node with the condition of having a direct sibling with a `display:none` style rule.

```css
div > div:has(+ div[style*="display:none"]),
div > div:last-child {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example 1 :</h3>
<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>  
  <div>C</div>  
  <div style="display:none">D</div>
  <div style="display:none">E</div> 
</div>
<h3>Example 2 :</h3>
<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>  
  <div>C</div>  
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div> 
</div>
```

`div:last-child` is only there to support the case where all the blocks would be visible, therefore there would be no sibbling but we want to apply the css rule anyway.

Please note that it only works because your hidden divs are sibblings.

Comment: This is the best answer imho. If you have a class to hide, you can use `div > div:has(~ .hidden)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

in other way, you can do it with javascript ,
in Jquery you can use something like:

```
$('div:visible').last()
```

*reedited

Answer (score 0):

`div:not([style*="display:none"], :has(~ div:not([style*="display:none"])))`

We need to get the last thing that matches `div:not([style*="display:none"])`. Let's call that x. We need to select x and then get the last one, which would be any x which does not have any x after it. To select something which has a selector after it, we use `:has(~ ...)` and we use `:not(...) to negate it`.

So `x:not(:has(~ x))`, or `div:not([style*="display:none"]):not(:has(~ div:not([style*="display:none"]))`, simplified to `div:not([style*="display:none"], :has(~ div:not([style*="display:none"]))`

Answer (score -3):

If you no longer need the hided elements, just use `element.remove()` instead of `element.style.display = 'none';`.

Comment: This removes the element from the DOM, it doesn't just hide it

Comment: Yes, of course.
 As i mentioned, it is useful for the cases where you no longer need the hided elements.
 It reminds solving the problem by questioning its necessity and reducing it into a simple and more clean job.