# CSS selector last visible child

Tags: css

Is there a way in CSS to apply CSS rules to a last visible child without knowing the class which makes an element invisible?

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item 5</li>
<ul>

<style>
  ul > li {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  // Remove right border from last visible child
  // This does not work of course, but this is what I am looking for
  ul > li:last-child:not([style="display: none"]) {
    border-right: none;
  }
</style>
```

To be clear: I'm looking for a rule-based selector not class-based in CSS not Javascript. But this answer [A CSS selector to get last visible div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div#answer-13866306) for example does not work. The problem here is that :last-child and :not can not be combined. :last-child([style="display: block"]) also does not work (when li has dispay: block), because it looks at the style attribute and not at the CSS rule.

Example in bootstrap (NOTE: hidden-md is an example, it could also be an other class which uses display:none):

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li class="hidden-md">Item 5</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: here you could do  `li[style] {border:none;}` but , what's the point if it is set at `display:none;` ?

Comment: @GCyrillus it might be placeholder...?

Comment: how do you set display:none ? through style attribute or a class or whatever. Whereever there is something peticular to it that CSS can see, use it :) my example only search for a li that has the style attribute since it is the one you want to select

Comment: @GCyrillus display: none is set by a class which would be unknown in this case.

Comment: are others getting a class too ? if not use li[class] if classes all start wicth the same caracters use li[class^="baba"] it will match .babac, .babawhatever

Comment: @GCyrillus No, in my case the invisible li gets class hidden-md (bootstrap) but I want to make it so that it would also work on a hidden-xs, etc. So it should only remove the border when it has the right screensize. So the question is really is there a way to select on rule rather than class?

Comment: @James Donnelly that does not answer my question

Comment: Is it always the last child that is invisible?

Comment: @Klaasvaak , for what you want you need javascript , to test a rule and then select previous sibbling element. CSS can not

Comment: @GCyrillus I guess the answer would be: it is not possible. I know it can be done with workaround but that is not the question.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible with CSS, however you could do this with jQuery. [Try this clumsy code](http://jsfiddle.net/sPK7m/2/).

**jQuery:**

```
 $('li').not(':hidden').last().addClass("red");
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li class="hideme">Item 4</li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hideme {
    display:none;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

---

**jQuery (previous solution):**

```
var $items = $($("li").get().reverse());

$items.each(function() {

    if ($(this).css("display") != "none") {
        $(this).addClass("red");
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: interesting but, are you sure it works ? http://jsfiddle.net/sPK7m/1/

Comment: Yes - it does. It adds class "red" to the last visible child.

Comment: oki, i understood he wanted any last of type  before hidden element

Comment: Great workaround but would not work for me because it also needs to be responsive. I guess it is not (yet) possible with just CSS.

Answer (score 3):

From CSS it is not possible :)

maybe if you draw the right border from the left border of next element or next pseudo element , you get **half of the job** done :http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ohKwv/

```
/* basic and naive workaround for borders */
  ul {
  text-align:center;
}li {
   display:inline-block;
   padding:0 1em
 }
li + li {
  border-left:solid;
}
ul:hover li:nth-child(even) {/* test : hide every even lis at once */
  display:none;
}
```