# Apply CSS style to last visible element

Tags: html, css

I have read this thread:
[A CSS selector to get last visible div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div)

However, it's not working for me. I wonder where I made mistake?

My CSS

```
.panel-i{
   position: relative;
   margin: 4px 0;
   text-align: right;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-right: none;    
   min-height: 76px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 8px 10px 0;
   -webkit-flex: 1 1 30%;
   -moz-flex: 1 1 30%;
   -ms-flex: 1 1 30%;
   flex: 1 1 30%;  /* flex-grow flex-shrink, flex-basis */
 }

.panel-i:not( [style*="display: none"]):last-child{
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="money_boxesRow">
   <div class="panel-i">
       <div class="panel-i-label">
          One Off Charge                                    
       </div>
       <span>                        
           £ <span id="total_one_off_charge">0.00</span>
       </span>
   </div>

   <!-- ... -->

   <div class="panel-i so_hide_commissions" style="display: none;">
      <div class="panel-i-label">
           Commission Total                                    
      </div>
      <span>                        
          £ <span id="total_commission">0.00</span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I trying to add border right to last visible box... But it's not appearing.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d584ob1p/1/)

Comment: Did you actually read the thread you are quoting? Or you just read an answer and thought it was correct?

Comment: "*I wonder where I made mistake?*" - you appear not to have read the answer you tried to use, and misunderstood the `:last-child` selector.

Comment: `.panel-i:not( [style*="display: none"]):last-child` selects the last child if it doesn't have `display:none;`.

Comment: Why don't you use table, it is a tabular view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d584ob1p/9/

Add

```
.panel-i:not(:first-child){
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Remove `border-right` from `.panel-i`

```
.panel-i{
    border-right: none;  /** remove **/
}
```

```css
.money_boxesRow {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -moz-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.panel-i {
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: right;
  min-height: 76px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px 10px 0;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 30%;
  -moz-flex: 1 1 30%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 30%;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  /* flex-grow flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}
.panel-i-label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.panel-i > span {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'PT sans narrow';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.panel-i:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="money_boxesRow">
  <div class="panel-i">
    <div class="panel-i-label">One Off Charge</div> <span>                        
            £ <span id="total_one_off_charge">0.00</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-i">
    <div class="panel-i-label">Monthly Charge</div> <span>                        
            £ <span id="total_monthly_charge">0.00</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-i">
    <div class="panel-i-label">Monthly Charge Total</div> <span>                        
            £ <span id="total_lease">0.00</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-i so_hide_commissions" style="display: none;">
    <div class="panel-i-label">Commission Total</div> <span>                        
            £ <span id="total_commission">0.00</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

The following selector:

```
.panel-i:not( [style*="display: none"]):last-child
```

Doesn't target the last in the `.panel-i:not( [style*="display: none"])` selection. It targets, the last child of the parent, on the condition that `.panel-i:not( [style*="display: none"])` is fulfilled.

`:last-child` is relative to the element's parent (hence `child` in the name). It is not relative to the selection that preceeds it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-right: none` from `.panel-i`

http://jsfiddle.net/d584ob1p/4/

Answer (score -3):

I recommend to use jQuery to achieve this. where you get more flexibility and options. I have updated the fiddle.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/d584ob1p/7/

```
$('.panel-i:visible:last').addClass('newclass')
```

Comment: JavaScript is generally not a good idea to rely on for layout.