# remove ::after when only one item is displayed

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the `::after` when only one `div.portfolio-item` is displayed. The reason being is because an image is attached to each of the items but when there is only one item it conflicts with the footer. I'm thinking that if there is only one time then a class should be added called one-item, that way I can control the ::after via CSS.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/1ku221ds/

jQuery...

```
function StringContainsAllItems(stringVal, items) {
if (items.length == 0 || items.length == null) {
    return false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log("Item: " + items[i]);
    if (stringVal.indexOf(items[i]) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}

$(function () {
//initialize first item
$('div.portfolio-item:visible:first').addClass("first-item");

var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='type-']");
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);

$checkboxes.change(function () {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {

        var selectorArray = [];

        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
            selectorArray.push($(this).attr('rel'));
            console.log($(this).attr('rel'));
        });

        $('[data-category]').hide() // hide all rows
        .filter(function () {
            return StringContainsAllItems($(this).data('category'), selectorArray);
        }).show(); // reduce set to matched and show    
    } else {
        $('[data-category]').show();
    }

    $('div.portfolio-item').removeClass("first-item");

    $('div.portfolio-item:visible:first').addClass("first-item");
});
});
```

So I added this function which doesn't work but you get an idea of what i'm trying to do...

```
$(function () {
var numItems = $('div.portfolio-item:visible').length;
if (numItems === 1) {
    $('div.portfolio-item:visible').addClass("one-item");
}
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your demo and code doesn't seem to match your question. You don't have any `::after` selector there. Also you haven't included any footer which you mention being the problem.

Comment: OK good point. I've added a new piece of code to the bottom which doesn't work but gives you an idea of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: why not use `:first-child`

Comment: because i'm using a jQuery filter system and the number of items show and hide depending on what is checked.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove an `::after` pseudo-element when there is only one child, you can use the [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) pseudo-class:

```css
.portfolio-item:after {
    content: 'foo';
}
.portfolio-item:only-child:after {
    content: none; /* or normal, unset, initial */
}
```

```css
.portfolio-item:after {
  content: 'foo';
}
.portfolio-item:only-child:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="portfolio-item"></div>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <div class="portfolio-item"></div>
  <div class="portfolio-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this is a good idea but it doesn't work with my filter system which shows and hides items. A class need to be added via jquery so I can hide the ::after on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if there is only one:

```
if( $("div.portfolio-item").first()[0] === $("div.portfolio-item").last()[0] )
```

if false, then use *jQuery.append()* instead *css::after*

```
$("div.portfolio-item").append("your content");
```

---

Check it:

```
var items = $("div.portfolio-item:visible");
if( items.first().get(0) !== items.last().get(0) ){
    items.addClass("one-item");
}
```

---

About the above code:

if the first is NOT equal the last, in other words: if there is NOT only one, then add the class

It works well

Comment: much easier to check length

Comment: I added this but doesn't work... `$(function () {
    if( $("div.portfolio-item").first()[0] === $("div.portfolio-item").last()[0] ) {
        $("div.portfolio-item").addClass("one-item");
    }
});`

I'm trying to add a class if only 1 item

Comment: will not test the opposite of what i want? I want to add a class if only one item.

Comment: i've updated the fiddle but my code adds the class `.one-item` to every item http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/1ku221ds/2/

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed here by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2048391/jyrkim

[Remove from DOM and add back again when check box true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922181/remove-from-dom-and-add-back-again-when-check-box-true-or-false/27923235#27923235)