# Applying/removing last-child styling in a dynamic listing

Tags: jquery, css

I have an unordered list with dynamic contents that can be shown/hidden, with all the li having border-bottom except the last child.

However, with jquery's .hide() applied to the last child, the element is just given display:none, therefore making the visually last element still showing its border-bottom.

What's the best way to solve this, that is also reusable across other similar ul within the project?

Comment: Please read **[`How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div), Please search before asking question.

Comment: @user2970115 my bad. did not find that one. thank you for linking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove border-bottom of last 'li' element, then use following CSS:-

```
.classname:last-child{
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

Where classname is the class added to the 'li' element.

`.hide()`  will hide the last 'li' element, not border.