# Selector does not work properly

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have container with class `.headerRightZone`
this container has elements with class `.btn`
some of them has class `.hidden`

Goal: I need to choose (write selector) the last visible (button without .hidden class) button

***myhtml.html***

```
<div class="headerRightZone">
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn">Button 1</a>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn">Button 2</a>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn">Button 3</a>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn hidden">Button 4</a>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn hidden">Button 5</a>
</div>
```

***mycss.css***

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.btn{
  background-color: #fff;
}

.headerRightZone .btn:not(.hidden):last-of-type{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

I wrote:

```
.headerRightZone .btn:not(.hidden):last-of-type
```

But it returns an empty array.

Attached [jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mbelko/po3fcuo6/)

What's wrong in the code? Why the array is empty?

Comment: "it returns an empty array" - sounds like this isn't CSS but is instead JavaScript. Could you provide the code you're using here?

Comment: Attached jsFiddle example. I expected the third anchor should be with red background

Comment: if you sure you want third anchor button to be red, you can select nth-child(3)  i just update your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/icenova/po3fcuo6/1/

Comment: no-no,  the count of hidden buttons can change, but the last visible should be red

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that last-of-type doesn't work how you are expecting it to.

It will only evaluate based on the element type, in this case `a`, it doesn't care about classes. The selector you have written can only ever affect the last anchor tag, regardless of what classes it has. So as your last element is not displayed, you are not seeing your styles being set.

Hiding different elements demonstrates this: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po3fcuo6/3/)

To solve your problem, you will need to use javascript or jQuery as this is beyond the capabilities of CSS.

Some good suggestions have already been made before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5275098/3759705)