# Complex CSS selector - how to require visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a CSS selector, which I have working so far:

```
input[placeholder*='mail']
```

but I'd like to ensure it's not finding invisible (ie: not visible) elements.

I've been trying `:visible` in various places in the pattern (because I couldn't find a good reference on the CSS selector lexer, but not luck with these:

```
input[placeholder:visible*='mail']
input:visible[placeholder*='mail']
input[placeholder*='mail']:visible
```

How do I do this? And anyone have a good reference on learning more complex selector formats?

Comment: What do you want to do? Is it just in CSS oder in jQuery?

Comment: I'm using selenium to parse web pages. Selenium has a way to find elements by their CSS selector.

Comment: There is no :visible CSS selector...

Comment: So how can I do this using CSS selector?

Comment: What would make it invisible? A class, an inline style, ...?

Comment: Oh hmmm. Hidden inputs, display none - are there other ways?

Comment: If you can do it in javascript you can check `element.offsetParent` which will  have a value if visible and null otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:visible` is a jQuery selector. Not a CSS one.

And you can't use it on an element's attribute like `placeholder.`

To check if there is an inputted value (which makes the placeholder "not visible"), you need to use some client-side code.

The jQuery would look like this:

```
$("input[placeholder*='mail']").each(function(){
  if( $(this).val() != "" ){
    // Do something.
    // ...
  }
});
```

---

To "filter out invisible elements" and keep only the visible ones:

```js
var visible = $("input[placeholder*='mail']:visible").length;
console.log(visible+" elements are visible.");
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="one" placeholder="My mail">
<input type="text" id="two" placeholder="Your mail">
<input type="text" id="three" class="hidden" placeholder="Junk mail">
<input type="hidden" id="four" placeholder="Cool mail">
```

Comment: why do we want to "check if there is an inputted value"? how does this imply visibility or lack thereof? sorry if I'm being dense. I really just want to filter out invisible DOM elements.

Comment: The way I understand your question... You want to target VISIBLE elements having a placeholder NOT visible.

Comment: I edited... Since, I misunderstood you question at first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS selector for `:visible`. You sould then work with classes and target the elements which have the class `.visible`. (Or NOT have the class `.visible`.

The `:visible` selector is only available in jQuery for example, which uses the pseudo selector for finding elements visible in current scroll view.

Comment: Hmm, I really just want to filter out invisible DOM elements and only select those that are visible. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with only CSS.

But you can do it with jquery and most probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275173/5688886) can help you.

Comment: I really just want to filter out invisible DOM elements. Is there a way to do that without jQuery?

Comment: As I follow your problem, there is no way of it.