# CSS selector for element that's in view

Tags: css, css-selectors, intersection-observer

Is there a CSS selector for things that are *in view*, i.e. visible within the viewport?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A CSS selector to get last visible div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div)

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript to achieve that. The modern way is to use `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: I think the modern way is `IntersectionObserver`, I was just wondering if there's a pre-CSS way...