# Add opacity to last visible element in html list

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have a list which has `overflow-y: scroll` property and a lot of items inside id.

I want to add opacity to last **visible** element in case we are not at the bottom of that list.

For example i have 100 elements and i see elements at index 5-10 (others are not visible) -> I want to add opacity to 10th element.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: use css `nth:child`

Comment: This is a great question. I suggest creating a small jsfiddle  so that everyone can play with their suggested answers and you can make sure it works. This looks very similar to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've provided an example that solves what you're looking for.

### A few notes

- This uses a gradient instead of a translucent overlay as this gives it less of a linear scroll effect

  - If you still want to implement this translucent filter, I recommend using the `scroll-snap` CSS property that @tacoshy suggested.
- I used the opacity property but this can easily be recreated using just the `rgba` property (again, going off of @tacoshy's comment)
- The overlay only disappears when the user has finished scrolling as opposed to while they're scrolling (this has performance benefits)
- The gradient overlays the scrollbar but this is fixable using the `-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-selector.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul')

list.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  if(list.scrollHeight - list.scrollTop == list.offsetHeight) {
    document.querySelector('.overlay').style.opacity = 0;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.overlay').style.opacity = 0.75;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
.overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve it with just a few lines of code :)

- Add an opaque layer (with `absolute` position) at the bottom of the list.
- Listen to the scroll event of the list element and if it reaches its end, hide the opaque layer. Otherwise, it will be visible, staying on the bottom of the list.

Comment: I highly recommend to use `transparency/RGBa` or `filter: blur;` istead of opacity which has it whole different variaty of issues as it is rendered last. Also should be combined with a `scroll-snap`. Alternativly it could be doable with `nth-child` and minor scripting.