# How to target last flex item

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of divs that can be either `display:none` or `display:flex` dynamically depending on a few conditions.

How do I check, since this is dynamic, what is the last div showing display flex?

My code is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: flex"></div>
  <div style="display: none"></div>
  <div style="display: flex"></div>
   <div style="display: none"></div>
</div>
```

As I say, the children might or might not be `display:flex` and might not necessarily be in this order or might be more items than this or not. I need to identify the last item with `display:flex` so I apply a `borderBottom` with javascript.

Comment: Why not use a class name to control both visibility _and_ to let you select the elements?

Comment: If applying the border to the container is not a suitable solution, then you need Javascript for this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A CSS selector to get last visible div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div)

Comment: you need JavaScript first get all the elements inside it and then check if it has flex and as you said it changes when it does re-run the function

Answer (score 1):

> I need to identify the last item with `display:flex` so I apply a borderBottom with javascript.

Since you have [js](/questions/tagged/js) available, consider using a [CSS selector targeting the `display: flex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-inline-style-attribute):

```
div[style="display: flex"]
```

Then get the last item in the array (eg: using [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)), thats the items you're looking for.

---

Pure css this won't be possible.

---

```js
const e = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('div[style="display: flex"]') ].pop();
e.style.border = '1px solid red';
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: flex">a</div>
  <div style="display: none">b</div>
  <div style="display: flex">c</div>
   <div style="display: none">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Use classes instead.

Comment: OP is clearly suffering from X/Y problem. Using JS to apply border bottom on the last flex item is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

change your styles to a class

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">a</div>
  <div class="none">b</div>
  <div class="flex">c</div>
</div>
```

A function to get it by class name

```
function le(){
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const elements = container.getElementsByClassName("flex")
return elements.item((elements.length - 1))
}
console.log(le())
```

and some csss

```css
.flex {
  display: flex
}

.none {
  display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simplest solution

```js
$(".container").each(function() {
    $('div:visible:last', this).css("background","red");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: flex">1</div>
  <div style="display: none">2</div>
  <div style="display: flex">3</div>
  <div style="display: none">4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```