# How can I access element selected from querySelectorAll based on visibility?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following code:

```
let codeBox1 = document.querySelectorAll(".codeBox1");
let codeBox2 = document.querySelectorAll(".codeBox2");
let codeBox3 = document.querySelectorAll(".codeBox3");
let codeBox4 = document.querySelectorAll(".codeBox4");

let OTPdigits = null;

const setOtpInputValue = () => {
 OTPdigits = codeBox1.value + codeBox2.value + codeBox3.value + codeBox4.value;
}
```

In the past, I was using `querySelector` and my code was working as well. But now I have to use `querySelectorAll` because I've added another 4-inputs (number type) to the DOM (one for Email OTP and the new one for Phone OTP).

Now I need to make `codeBox1` to be either `codeBox1[0]` or `codeBox1[1]` when I access it inside `setOtpInputValue()` method. The logic should be based on visibility. Sinde always one of the OTP inputs is visible.

Any idea how can I handle that?

Comment: PLease add desired output, not sure what your asking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A CSS selector to get last visible div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div)

Comment: Or If I do understand, convert to an array: `[ ...document.querySelectorAll("input") ]` then you can use `arr[0]` etc

Comment: @0stone0 the value of `OTPdigits` is `NaN` when I call `setOtpInputValue`. Because `codeBox1`, `codeBox2`, and ... are selected by `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: But what is the desired output of OTPdigits?

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce()` to 'combine' the inputs. Use a fallback for the non-visible elements if needed

```js
const allBoxes = [ ...document.querySelectorAll("input") ]

let OTPdigits = allBoxes.reduce(
  (p, c) => (p + c.value)
, '');

console.log(OTPdigits)
```

```html
<input class='codeBox1' type='number'>
<input class='codeBox2' type='number' value=5>
<input class='codeBox3' type='number' style='display: none'>
<input class='codeBox4' type='number'>
```

---

If you just need the visible elements, change the selector to:

```
[ ...document.querySelectorAll("input:not([style='display:none'])") ]
```

Or use another way to check [if the element is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom), so you can add an `if` in the reduce:

```
let OTPdigits = allBoxes.reduce((p, c) => 
    (p + (c.offsetParent === null ? '' : c.value))
, '');
```

Comment: Shouldn't initialValue for reduce be `''`?

Comment: Why? Op wants an integer as output right?

Comment: For example, the otp is "1234", your output would be 10 instead of 1234. If total is the expected output, 1234 is same as 4321 which is wrong. Having input type number helps opening numeric keyboard on mobile devices but that does not mean we do arithmetic addition on them.

Comment: Ahh, your completely right, changed my answer. THanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess my question is not clear enough so your answer doesn't address my question. But I learned some tricks from your answer and Upvoted!

Comment: If you, [as asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887742/how-can-i-access-element-selected-from-queryselectorall-based-on-visibility/74887881?noredirect=1#comment132158502_74887742) can provide your expected behaviour, with 1/2 examples, I can probably improve my answer.