# Select first and last visible items in a list

Tags: css

Given a container with div children, some of which might have a `.hidden` class, how can I select the first and last visible items (that don't have that class), using only css?

I tried:

`div:not(.hidden):last-child` Which doesn't work because last-child is always the last child.

I mean in 2 declarations, not both at the same time.

Comment: I don't think css is robust enough for finding the first and last matched selector in a list but you could use jQuery as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275173/7375347). So you could have the jQuery selector to be something like `$('div:not(.hidden):last')` and  `$('div:not(.hidden):first')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `:nth-child()` / `:nth-last-child()` pseudo-classes. Note that [support is a little spotty](https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of), especially on mobile

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: .2;
}

li:nth-child(1 of :not(.hidden)),
li:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.hidden)) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="hidden">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li class="hidden">Five</li>
</ul>
```

Further reading:

- [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [:nth-last-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

Comment: Impressive, that did work, even though vscode gets confused about the syntax haha.  Thanks.